# How to run R script through multiple directories via windows Task Scheduler

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, cron-task, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to automate some reports in R through the Windows Task Scheduler. The issue is that I keep getting 0x1 error codes and I believe it is because the automated script is using the source() function in R to call other scripts that are not in the same directory.

I have tried creating a .bat file but it runs into the same problem. My user does have security rights, as well.

```
@echo off 
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\me\data\report\file.R"
pause
```

I've also tried:

```
@echo off 
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\Rscript.exe" -e"source('C:/Users/me/data/report/file.R')"
```

Does anybody know how to automate a script that would go through multiple directories? Or do I really have to clone each of these scripts and put all of them in the same folder just to automate things?

Comment: Perhaps you can set the proper working directory using `setwd()` inside the file.R - script you are calling? Or perhaps `source` using the absolute path of the files you want to load.

Comment: Is there a reason you have different backslashes? R can be sensitive to wrongly formatted backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to put them all in the same directory.

I created a script that calls another script in another directory and created a task with `taskscheduleR`.

It worked for me so I don't think the issue has to do with the `source()`.

Nevertheless, your issue is hard to reproduce. But it might have something to do with administrator roles. I would suggest that you talk to your IT-department if you have one.

```r
source("C:/Users/ADMFIWA/Documents/task-test-other/other-summary.R")

library(taskscheduleR)
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "test",
                     rscript = "C:/Users/ADMFIWA/Documents/task-test/summary.R", 
                     schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M"))
#> [1] "SUCCESS: The scheduled task \"test\" has successfully been created."
```

Created on 2019-03-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: In your example, you use source before the task is scheduled but are there source() codes within the rscript that you define in the taskscheduler_create() function? I'm wondering if that is significant difference.

Comment: Yes, `source()` is the only line of code that I am using in the `summary.R` script.

Comment: I just reloaded my scripts and checked my user-role like you suggested and it worked. Thanks for the source() clarification!